# Is there an Oracle analytic function that can help turn this SQL into a view?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, sql-view

Consider this table (simplified) which could have lots of rows:

```
CREATE TABLE v
(
   m VARCHAR2(50),
   ts date,
   v NUMBER
)
/
```

Then the following works great as a query:

```
SELECT
   m,
   MIN(ts) min_ts,
   MAX(ts) max_ts
FROM
   v
WHERE 
   TO_DATE('2016-01-10','YYYY-MM-DD') <= ts AND
   ts < TO_DATE('2016-01-20','YYYY-MM-DD') AND
   m = '123'
GROUP BY
   m
/
```

Where the TO_DATES and '123' represent user provided filter criteria. Now when I try to convert this SQL to a view and put the criteria on it, I run into problems:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vv AS
SELECT
   m,
   MIN(ts) min_ts,
   MAX(ts) max_ts
FROM
   v
GROUP BY
   m
/
```

I can't provide the ts date filter on the view as Oracle will already have grouped the result, for example, the following will not work (ORA-00904: "TS": invalid identifier):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   vv
WHERE 
   TO_DATE('2016-01-10','YYYY-MM-DD') <= ts AND
   ts < TO_DATE('2016-01-20','YYYY-MM-DD') AND
   m='123'
/
```

So are there any Oracle analytical etc. functions that can help in this scenario to turn the SQL into a view?

Comment: Does it have to be callable like that, in a `from` clause? Will you be joining it to other things? (Wondering if a function returning a ref cursor would be suitable. Otherwise a parameterised view using a context is possible but can be confusing, and the context needs to be built; or a function returning a collection - depends on the usage required though)

Comment: You would need to do this with a user-defined table function.  Oracle (and SQL in general) doesn't have the concept of parameterized views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a pipelined table function in a package using a dummy view and a %ROWTYPE on that view, something like:

```
-- Dummy view
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vv AS
SELECT
   m,
   MIN(ts) min_ts,
   MAX(ts) max_ts
FROM
   v
WHERE
   1=0
GROUP BY
   m
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE vv_utl
AS
   TYPE tt_vv IS TABLE OF vv%ROWTYPE;

   FUNCTION load
   (
      ifromts IN date,
      itots IN date,
      im IN varchar2 default null
   ) RETURN tt_vv PIPELINED;   
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY vv_utl
AS
   FUNCTION load
   (
      ifromts IN date,
      itots IN date,
      im IN varchar2 default null
   ) RETURN tt_vv PIPELINED  
   AS
      CURSOR vv_cur IS
      SELECT
         m,
         MIN(ts) min_ts,
         MAX(ts) max_ts
      FROM
         v
      WHERE
         ifromts <= ts AND
         ts < itots AND
         m = nvl(im,m)
      GROUP BY
         m;
   BEGIN
      FOR rec IN vv_cur LOOP
         pipe row(rec);
      END LOOP;
   END;
END;
/

-- Test 
SELECT
   *
FROM
   table(
      vv_utl.load(
         TO_DATE('2016-01-10','YYYY-MM-DD'),
         TO_DATE('2016-01-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
         )
      ) 
/
```

I was worried about performance of the pipelined table function (I read somewhere that they do not cache their results) and as I could not make my function deterministic (one way to get Oracle to cache the results), I went for a straight view solution using a package to store my parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE vv_param
AS
   PROCEDURE set
   (
      ifromts IN date,
      itots IN date,
      im IN varchar2 default null
   );

   FUNCTION get_fromts RETURN DATE;
   FUNCTION get_tots RETURN DATE;
   FUNCTION get_m RETURN VARCHAR2;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY vv_param
AS
   lfromts date;
   ltots date;
   lm varchar2(50);

   PROCEDURE set
   (
      ifromts IN date,
      itots IN date,
      im IN varchar2 default null
   )
   AS
   BEGIN
       lfromts := ifromts;
       ltots := itots;
       lm := im;
   END;

   FUNCTION get_fromts RETURN DATE AS BEGIN RETURN lfromts; END;
   FUNCTION get_tots RETURN DATE AS BEGIN RETURN ltots; END;
   FUNCTION get_m RETURN VARCHAR2 AS BEGIN RETURN lm; END;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vv AS
SELECT
   m,
   MIN(ts) min_ts,
   MAX(ts) max_ts
FROM
   v
WHERE
   vv_param.get_fromts <= ts AND
   ts < vv_param.get_tots AND
   m = nvl(vv_param.get_m,m)
GROUP BY
   m
/

BEGIN
   vv_param.set(
      TO_DATE('2016-01-10','YYYY-MM-DD'), 
      TO_DATE('2016-01-20','YYYY-MM-DD')
      );
END;
/

-- Test 
SELECT
   *
FROM
   vv
/
```

Also when using a pipelined table function I could not see the details of the EXPLAIN PLAN as the SQL was hidden in the package function. Now an EXPLAIN PLAN on the view works as per normal.

This example is obviously very simple but in my actual implementation there are many of these views, many depending on other views like this. Using the package variable solution allowed me to share them across all these views. Any yes, its not without its pitfalls, e.g. one could forget to set the variables and if you are re-using the session like in ODP.NET, you could be using old values and so get the wrong result. So only time will tell if this was the right way to go!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it, but it requires the use of a context, along with the necessary package to do the setting/clearing of the context. You'd need to test with your data to see if this is performant enough.

**Create New Context**

```
create or replace context test_context using pkg_context_utils;
```

**Create package to set new context**

```
create or replace package pkg_context_utils
as
  procedure set_date (p_date in date);
  procedure clear_date;
end pkg_context_utils;
/

create or replace  package body pkg_context_utils
as
  procedure set_date (p_date in date)
  is
  begin
    dbms_session.set_context (namespace => 'test_context',
                              attribute => 'test_date',
                              value     => p_date);
  end set_date;

  procedure clear_date
  is
  begin
    dbms_session.clear_context(namespace => 'test_context',
                               client_id => null,
                               attribute => 'test_date');
  end clear_date;

end pkg_context_utils;
/
```

**Create a view using the context in the where clause**

```
create or replace view test_view
as
select * from dual where sys_context('test_context', 'test_date') > sysdate;
```

**Run the view with no context set**

```
select * from test_view;

no rows selected.
```

**Set the context to be after the current date**

```
begin
  pkg_context_utils.set_date(trunc(sysdate + 1));
end;
/

select * from test_view;

DUMMY
-----
X
```

**Set the context to before the current date**

```
begin
  pkg_context_utils.set_date(trunc(sysdate));
end;
/

select * from test_view;

no rows selected.
```

Comment: This quite interesting way of doing it. I suppose one could use a user defined package variable instead of sys_context? I have gone for a pipelined function approach but am worried about performance so not sure if this is going to work for me.